# Qual è il significato di "momenti di reazione" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> «In certi **momenti di reazione** sarei portato ad ammettere che mi sposai per fare dispetto a Enzina. Ma non sarebbe la verità. La verità è che avevo bisogno di un affetto. Lo cercai sposandomi. Piano piano, e con la miseria che avevamo patito insieme, mi ero veramente innamorato di mia moglie. Il nostro non era più soltanto un modo di tenersi per la mano... Non aver mai nessuno con cui espandersi, nessuno che ti sappia capire e che ti aiuti a farti coraggio...».

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "momenti di reazione" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il termine "reazione" in parecchi dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 1):

Il significato di [reazione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/reazione/) che a mio parere maggiormente si adatta al contesto da te indicato è il seguente:

> 4 d. In psichiatria, sindrome di vario tipo: r. esogena, sindrome
>   psicotica dovuta a un agente che non sia in rapporto né con la
>   costituzione né con la disposizione del soggetto; r. psicogena,
>   sindrome che insorge a seguito di un fatto realmente vissuto ricco di
>   contenuto emotivo, in rapporto diretto, anche di tempo, con il fatto
>   stesso (per es., lo stato depressivo che insorge dopo un grave lutto).

Non sono un esperto in materia, ma direi che la reazione indicata dall'autore potrebbe essere quella psicogena, cioè in particolari momenti in cui ci si ritrova sotto pressione psicologica, ad esempio per contrattempi nella vita, si è portati a comportarsi ed avere atteggiamenti diversi dal normale.

In uno di questi momenti particolari l'autore sarebbe portato ad ammettere che

> mi sposai per fare dispetto a Enzina. Ma non sarebbe la verità.

Comment: Personalmente, quella psichiatrica mi sembra un'accezione troppo tecnica, e dubito molto che già si usasse negli anni '40. Penso che si riferisca solo ai momenti in cui semplicemente _regisce_ alle cose che non vanno, all'insoddisfazione del suo stato attuale (o chissà che altro: non ho letto il libro).

Comment: _regisce_ = _reagisce_, ovviamente...

Comment: Penso che @DaG abbia ragione. Nel libro non si spiega un gran ché su questo matrimonio, ma c'è qualche passaggio che viene a dire che non andava bene.